# 500 (Service unavailable (with message))

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I trying to call `db_update()` after sending jquery post, so I need to include drupal_bootstrap to use Drupal functions, here is my code :

MyModuleAPI.php

```
if (!defined('DRUPAL_ROOT')) {
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 'mysite');
    chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
}
include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);

function set_server($host,$port){

        db_update('server')...
                    ->execute();
     ...
}

$query = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query']: null;
$params = isset($_POST['params']) ? $_POST['params']: null;

switch ($query)
{   case "set_server" :
       ...
        set_server($host,$port);
        break;

}
```

MyModuleAjax.js

```
function ajax_set_server(serverHost,serverport){
    var pathUrl="path/to/includes/MyModuleAPI.php";

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pathUrl,
            data: {query: "set_server", params:[serverHost,serverport]},
            success: function (response) {                
                console.log("set server resp "+response);
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

My problem is when sending the request I get:

```
POST http://localhost/path/to/includes/MyModuleAPI.php 500 (Service unavailable (with message))
```

I don't know if the problem is from including bootstrap or if it is already legal there. Any help please.

Comment: Use your browser `developer tools` -> `network` tab and look for that request - what's the `response preview` output? My guess that there's a php error and the mentioned output would help you to locate the bug.

Comment: @OfirBaruch it's very helpful, I get the explicit error message now, thank you

Comment: If I write it as an answer, would you accept it? Or you would like me to help you with your error message as well?

Comment: it's OK since I get the explicit error message I can fix it. Thank you @OfirBaruch , you may write an answer I will accept it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, getting a 500 error when trying to send data to a php file means that there's something wrong with the php code in that file.

While I cannot be sure what's the error might be I sure can show you how to see the php error by using `developers tools`. Select the `network` tab in order to see all the requests (your ajax request should appear among them, with the target php file name). Now select that request and under `response preview` you should see the php error that causing the mentioned above 500 error.

After you'd fix that error, your request should work (200 code - success).